# arcpy.listfields for a beginner

Tags: arcpy

I am very bad at Python and I can't even get this [script](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001p000000) to work and the worst about this is that its really small script.

Let's say I have a shapefile in C:\temp\test.shp and I want to list all the field names in that shapefile.

Let's say a featureclass with 4 fieldnames: TYPE, NAME, SPEED, AREA
and I want to list the fieldnames. I thought this worked but it did not:

```
import arcpy

fclass = "C:/Data/Municipal.gdb/Hospitals"
fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass)]
```

What do I need to think about if I have a featureclass in .GDB or want to use a featureclass from MXD.

Does Python list in window the field names or can I get an output to like .txt I am interested in both ways so I can learn.

Comment: Edit your question to show the code YOU have used which is failing.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or are you just not seeing any output?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that this isn't working? The script you have there doesn't actually *do* anything. The variable "fieldnames" should contain a list of all fields, however you are not displaying them. What happens if you loop through the list and print the results?
ie. for fieldname in fieldnames:
        print fieldname

Answer (score 5):

```
import arcpy

# r means raw string and will ignore /n, /t, special characters etc.
>>> shp = r'C:\TEMP\SHP\Airport.shp'  
>>> shp_fields = arcpy.ListFields(shp)
```

shp_fields is now a list of '[describe field objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000004n000000)'

Lets see what's inside that list

```
>>> print shp_fields
>>> [<Field object at 0x303acd0[0x3110e78]>, <Field object at 0x303ae10[0x3110c80]>, <Field object at 0x303acf0[0x3110f38]>,...]
```

Lets deconstruct the 'describe field object' to get the desired information.

```
>>> shp_field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
```

or

```
>>> shp_field_names = [f.baseName for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
```

or

```
>>> shp_field_name = [f.aliasName for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
```

When you say 'I thought this worked but it didn't' there are a number of things that can go wrong.

Your logic and syntax are correct and shouldn't raise an error or exception. It is, however, difficult to determine what it is that you're trying to accomplish.

Check if python is installed properly.

Check if the arcpy site-package is import-able.

Comment: thanks! the import arcpy, and print function works, but when I am trying to run shp_field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)] it complains. EDIT: basename works but where does the result go?/EDIT
what does "for f in" means?
I just want a table of all the fields in attribut table, to list them. I guess I can do it by exporting to .dbf and then reorder in excel but thats not fun.

Comment: @jonaktiv I'm happy to answer questions aimed at solving a particular problem. Your question of "Where does the result go?" which is related to simple variable assignment a very basic question. I'd suggest you take a look at the Python Tutorial here: http://bit.ly/1FcFAt2

Comment: my last edit did not come through, when I wrote print shp_fields after shp_fields = [f.baseName for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]

then I saw my result. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me and returned a list of field names with data type and data length:

```
import arcpy

# For each field in the Hospitals feature class, print
#  the field name, type, and length.
fields = arcpy.ListFields(r"C:\Users\utilavt\Documents\ArcGIS\Parcel_Updates\shps\PARCELS.shp")

for field in fields:
    print("{0} is a type of {1} with a length of {2}"
          .format(field.name, field.type, field.length))
```